# Fit a part of the series and transform the whole series

Tags: python, normalization

I have a series of float values; length = 120 values
I am trying to normalize the series based on the last 60 values of the series, and transform the entire series.

Series = StandardScalar.fit(series[-84:]) # This is the portion of the series I want to calculate the mean and std dev for.

And, transform the whole series on the basis of the mean and std dev of series[-84:].

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

Fit first for the `[-84:]` and then `fit_transform` the whole serie. Small example here:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd':6, 'e':0.1}
series = pd.Series(data=d)

df = pd.DataFrame({'val':series})
sc = StandardScaler()

# 1) Fit scaler for last x values in your case -84
norm = sc.fit(df[-3:]) # fit for last 3 values

# 2) Transform whole dataset
normalized = norm.transform(df)
```